# Cloud Foundry router cannot find api.xx.xxxx.com/info (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry

Finally managed to successfully deploy cloud foundry to AWS. 
Mostly following instructions from http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/ec2/bootstrap-aws-vpc.html

Its failing at the validation step that is to get a success response for the following:

```
curl api.subdomain.domain/info
```

Of course I have substituted the subdomain and domain appropriately.

I am getting the error:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('api.XX.XXXXX.com') does not exist.
```

The request is coming till the Cloud foundry router `router_z1`. And I can see this error in the logs for `router_z1`.

Here is output of my `bosh vms` command:

```
------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
| Job/index                          | State   | Resource Pool | IPs          |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
| unknown/unknown                    | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.16.254 |
| unknown/unknown                    | running | medium_z2     | 10.10.81.4   |
| unknown/unknown                    | running | small_errand  | 10.10.17.1   |
| unknown/unknown                    | running | small_errand  | 10.10.17.0   |
| api_worker_z1/0                    | running | small_z1      | 10.10.17.20  |
| api_z1/0                           | running | large_z1      | 10.10.17.18  |
| clock_global/0                     | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.17.19  |
| etcd_z1/0                          | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.16.20  |
| hm9000_z1/0                        | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.17.21  |
| loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1/0 | running | small_z1      | 10.10.16.34  |
| loggregator_z1/0                   | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.16.31  |
| login_z1/0                         | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.17.17  |
| nats_z1/0                          | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.16.11  |
| router_z1/0                        | running | router_z1     | 10.10.16.15  |
| runner_z1/0                        | running | runner_z1     | 10.10.17.22  |
| stats_z1/0                         | running | small_z1      | 10.10.17.15  |
| uaa_z1/0                           | running | medium_z1     | 10.10.17.16  |
+------------------------------------+---------+---------------+--------------+
```

The only change that I made in the CF deployment manifest was to eliminate instance from `zone 2`. The reason being AWS default limit for number of instances on EC2 in a particular region is 20.

Any pointers on how to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Couple of issues:

1. In the CF deployment manifest make sure the system domain property
   is `<BOSH_VPC_SUBDOMAIN>.<BOSH_VPC_DOMAIN>`. That is if you have
   reserved `cf.example.com` for cloud foundry PaaS. Make sure
   cf.example.com is what `system_domain` property in your cloud
   foundry deployment manifest refers to. Infact `example.com` should
   not appear in your deployment manifest anywhere without `cf.`.
   Through out the deployment manifest it is always `cf.example.com`
2. Do not use '@' in any of the passwords within the deployment
   manifest. I have logged a bug for this in cf-releases:
   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/issues/527